# Is it possible to use 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider without installation?

Tags: excel, oledb

I have an Excel-reading library that depends on the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider - I would like a way to use it without being forced to install the Access Database Engine.

Is it possible? e.g. xcopy deploy + clever COM trickery.

Comment: Not to be snarky, but you want to install it without using the actual installer? What problem are you trying to solve with this -- are you trying to avoid needing admin privileges, or something? (Also, there are other/better solutions to reading Excel that don't rely on this provider, but that's a different can of worms.)

Comment: The problem we are trying to avoid is a 200MB installer every single place we want our software to run, just in order to load a small Excel file. We use a very nice library called LinqToExcel, unfortunately it has this dependency. Hence we are trying to have our cake and eat it.

Comment: Sounds like a case of penny wise, pound foolish, because even if you find a way to do this (and I doubt it, but who knows) you're completely on your own if problems occur, since this scenario is not going to be supported by MS. So now you've got a program that cleverly avoids a big installer, in exchange for something that's going to be a nightmare to support across machines. As convenient as LinqToExcel is to you, if it's just a "small Excel", you should be able to make do without it and use a library that parses Excel directly. Or have the user save CSV.

Comment: We have now switched library. As for "nightmare to support" nobody said we only sought an unsupported hack. Anyway, obviously this is an ancient, legacy technology so modern modular easily-distributable software components can't be expected. It would be cool to access Excel via SQL without 200MB installer crap though...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not enough point to comment

But from my understanding in your question, the short answer is No. It's like you want to have a house but you don't to build it on the solid surface.

Perhaps you can explain why you can't install Access Database Engine and what you are trying to achieve in detail so we can get a work around in this instead

Comment: I am happy to have the house, I just don't want to have it "installed'. Seems to be a fairly common requirement in software these days, no? For example SQL CE use to have to be installed, work arounds exists to avoid installing, and eventually they made it install-free

Comment: Well, if you have the house, you need to place it somewhere solid so that it can be used. For Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider, it's a DLL directly under Access Database Engine. Access Database Engine is the surface for your house to stand. So it's fundamental we need the surface first. Perhaps you can send a feedback to Microsoft and ask for a work around in your situation.